# Getting info in lldb like gdb's info mach-regions?

Tags: debugging, gdb, remote-debugging, lldb

I have a 3rd party app I am debugging and part of the data I need to look at is in an area of memory allocated by the program after it starts up. If I am in gdb, and I type 'info mach-sections' it gives me a listing of all the allocated memory addresses.

For the life of me I cannot find anything similar in lldb. The closest I can find is image dump sections, but that only shows the memory allocated in those sections, not any memory allocated by them after the program started up.

For a multitude of reasons, I'd prefer to be debugging this in lldb, but it's the one command I need to use that I cannot figure out the correct format for, to get the allocated memory ranges. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That command has not been ported over to lldb yet.  Please file a feature request for this (since this is Mac specific http://bugreporter.apple.com is the most appropriate venue.)

Note you can get the same information from the vmmap tool or from Instruments.